# Return a number from a google search in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel file with about 6,000 entries on it, listing company, employees, and their titles. What I'd like to do is lookup the number of employees the company  has, and return that information in a column. I think there are some similar ideas here already, returning, for example, the number of results, or the first hyperlink, but I don't have enough VBA knowledge to alter those to get what I need to be honest. Here's the number of results macro:

```
Dim searchWords As String

With Sheets("Sheet1")
RowCount = 2
Do While .Range("A" & RowCount) <> ""
searchWords = .Range("A" & RowCount).Value

' Get keywords and validate by adding + for spaces between
searchWords = Replace$(searchWords, " ", "+")

' Obtain the source code for the Google-searchterm webpage
search_url = "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" & searchWords & "&meta="""
Set search_http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
search_http.Open "GET", search_url, False
search_http.send
results_var = search_http.responsetext
Set search_http = Nothing

' Find the number of results and post to sheet
pos_1 = InStr(1, results_var, "div id=" & Chr(34) & "resultStats", vbTextCompare) + 21
If pos_1 = 21 Then
NumberofResults = 0
Else
pos_2 = InStr(pos_1, results_var, "result", vbTextCompare) - 1
NumberofResults = Val(Replace(Replace(Mid(results_var, pos_1, pos_2 - pos_1), ",", ""), "About", ""))
End If
Range("B" & RowCount) = NumberofResults
RowCount = RowCount + 1
Loop
End With
End Sub
```

I believe this is the variable that Google uses for the number of employees :

```
<div class="Z0LcW">17,000
```

So I think by replacing `div id=` with `div class=` and `"resultStats"` with `"Z0LcW"` That will get me most of the way there? This is all completely new territory for me, I just checked multiple source pages after searching for number of employees, and that was consistently the variable that related to the number of employees.

I know how to do the search - just combine company name with "number of employees" and hyperlink it:
[image]

And it looks like it should be fairly easy to pull the number of employees, as Google returns it as the first item usually, but getting everything to play nice is beyond me. Any help would be much appreciated!
[image]

Comment: Consider using Selenium instead of trying to use string matching functions to parse HTML.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I don't think I'd be able to figure that out. I've been looking at Selenium's website and I really have no idea where to start. I have fairly low levels of programming knowledge, I'm pretty comfortable in Excel, but beyond that, I have extremely basic levels of knowledge. I can usually figure something out given enough time, but that looks like it would take me a couple months haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Tool  > References: Microsoft Internet Controls
Tool  > References: Microsoft HTML Object Library

Sub GetHits()

Dim element As IHTMLElement
Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim count As Long
Dim erow As Long

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

' open Internet Explorer in memory, and go to website
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True

For i = 2 To lastRow

    ie.navigate "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1)
    ' Wait until IE has loaded the web page
    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.StatusBar = "Loading Web page . . . "
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set html = ie.document
    Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("Z0LcW")

        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i) = html.getElementsByClassName("Z0LcW")(0).innerText
        Debug.Print i
Next i

End Sub
```

In cells A2:A5, you should  have something like this.

```
apple number of employees
disney number of employees
IBM number of employees
```

That's your Google search.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Hey Asher, thanks so much for the help! Just a quick question, I'm getting a 
"run-time error 91 - object variable or with block variable not set" 
at this part:

``` Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" &i) = oElement(i).innerText
```
That's the start of the program running through column A (with the i+1's) right? Is it giving me that error because I'm running VB for Applications rather than VB.net? I did a quick search and read that VB object variables require the Set keyword to be assigned, and this was taken out in VB.net, so maybe that's my problem?

Comment: oElement is defined as an object at the top of the program, so I'm totally lost on why I keep getting that error! I've tried With, and Set directly before, neither worked; thought that innerText might need to be innerHtml so tried that, that didn't work, and I can't think of anything else that might help, so if you've got any ideas, it would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Ok, I just made some major changes to my original post.  Try the updated code.  I'm sure this will work for you.  Remember, run this from Excel, not VB.NET.

Comment: Hey Asher so that seems to work until you run into one that doesn't have a ```div class = Z0LcW``` . Think you'd have to put an ```IF``` statement in there like if "Z0LcW" not found in html, then return N/A, but I'm not sure on the syntax of a statement like that in VBA. Again, total noob haha

Comment: Oh interesting! Sometimes it will return the location (Abbott Laboratories Company number of employees returns Chicago, Illinois, United States), but only sometimes, the other times it will run into a 91 error code. And it will also run into an error if one of the strings contains an ampersand (&). Neat! Haha so just run a search / replace on & for and, and that takes care of that problem, but I'm not sure on the other one

Comment: I saw some weird things too.  I guess if the data isn't there, it just isn't there.  You are only seeing what Google can find for you.